# How are external url's resolved by FreeIPA?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, freeipa

We are running FreeIPA version 4.6.8 on Centos 7.9.2009 and have multiple dns zones defined for local resources running inside our private network. For this to work we enter our ipa server's IP address as the DNS server on our internal network. Everything works as expected but I'm confused as to how external sites are being resolved. If I execute `dig google.com`, the response shows the ipa server IP is queried as shown below.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.5 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6083
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.250.65.174

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.             150064  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.             150064  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             150064  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             150064  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.         150040  IN      A       216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.         150040  IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.         150040  IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.         150040  IN      A       216.239.38.10
ns2.google.com.         150040  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns1.google.com.         150040  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
ns3.google.com.         150040  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
ns4.google.com.         150040  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 10.xx.xx.xx#53(10.xx.xx.xx)  <<<---- Our FreeIPA server IP
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 26 11:38:02 EDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 303
```

Since I do not have a global forwarder defined or any other forwarders defined, I don't understand which DNS server is queried next if a DNS zone does not exist in our FreeIPA? Are the name servers defined in /etc/resolv.conf looked at?

What I am try to figure out is how to implement DNS filtering. My goal is to have DNS queries first look into FreeIPA to resolve local resources and then look to the DNS server at 185.228.168.10 (CleanBrowsing Filtered DNS).

Comment: I'd personally make sure that no other DNS servers are used in my IPA environment (mainly in resolv.conf) besides the IPA servers, then define a global forwarder of `185.228.168.10`. Have you run this test from the IPA box itself to see if it succeeds? If it doesn't, the lookup should be something client side.

Comment: For the purpose of the test I described above, I did run from the IPA server after disabling the entries in resolv.conf. I'll try defining a global forwarder as suggested.